# Create new word document based on template from browser/javascript

Tags: javascript, templates, web, sharepoint, ms-office

I'm looking for a way to create/open a new word document based on a selected template (dotx) using a browser/javascript.

Basically what I want to achive is the same functionality thats in sharepoint where you can from a menu create a new document based of a template.

[image: Create document based on template from within sharepoint]

Any ideas of where to start?
I have been googling for a solution but all I could find was how to do this if your javascript is running in the same context as sharepoint. However, I would like to do this outside of the context of sharepoint, but its fine if I need to add a few libraries to my site to be able to support this kind of functionality.

Comment: When you say "create a new document", do you mean for download? How exactly will this work? Is the user supposed to edit the newly created document in the browser? Does is have to be a Word document? What is the end goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that office has support for some uris that can be used for this case..
for instance:
ms-word:nft|u|{address to dotx-file} would create a link that opens up a new word document based on the target template.
More regarding the uris can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/office-uri-schemes